# how to use substr get string from right hand side in c++

Tags: c++, string, substr

I have a string of numbers for example 469111252 and I know how to split from left-hand side but how to use substr to split it from right-hand side?

If digitsPerNode = 2

from left 46 91 11 25 2

But I want to get from right 52 12 11 69 4

```
//left hand side parse
for (int i=0;i<num.length(); i+=digitsPerNode) {
    splitNum = num.substr(i,digitsPerNode);
}
```

Comment: Instead of going from low to high, go from high to low?

Comment: Have you looked into reverse iterators?

Comment: Still learning to deal with string I will go check. It is not straight forward when use substr from right-hand side.

Comment: Looks like I need reverse iterator to solve this. Is there a simple way without  using it just substr?

Comment: Personally, if this is not performance critical, or you can deal with `2 * O(N)`, then I would just use `std::reverse` to reverse the string and then go from the front like you do right now.  Makes dealing with this much easier.

Comment: Yeah I did reverse(num.begin(),num.end()). I feel it's easier to read this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with reverse function

```
DoublyLinkedList::DoublyLinkedList(string value, string dPerNode)
{
    digitsPerNode = stoi(dPerNode);
    string subString;
    reverse(value.begin(), value.end());
    for (int i = 0; i <= value.length(); i += digitsPerNode)
    {
        //cut string by digitsPerNode Ex: 3 500 123 412
        subString = value.substr(i, digitsPerNode);
        reverse(subString.begin(), subString.end());
        insertAtHead(subString);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Count from top to bottom not from bottom to top.

```
int numlength=num.length();

if(numlength%2==1)
numlength+=1;

    for(int i=numlength;i>=0;i-=digitsPerNode)
    {
        splitNum = num.substr(i,digitsPerNode);
    {
```

Comment: You have a few typos so this will never compile.  You are also using an `int` which, for larger strings could be an issue.

Comment: I tried it. I got run-time error out of range should be i-=

Comment: Try changing i> to i>=

Comment: If i goes to 0 it can be substr(0,-2)

Comment: @IEssing your begin state is wrong, also you will not get last sentence shorten than `digitsPerNode`

Answer (score 0):

```
string a = "1234567890-=4";
for (int i = a.length() - 2; i >= -1; i = i - 2)
{
    if (i < 0) cout << a.substr(i+1, 1) << endl;
    else cout << a.substr(i, 2) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Compiler keep warning me about the type conversion from type_t to int because of int i and a.length() are different type